# flutter plugin is slow

Tags: flutter, plugins, contacts

I'm using contacts_service 0.4.6 plugin to load phoneBook contacts into my flutter app, but it is very slow, how can I increase the contacts loading speed? or is there any speeder plugin to load contacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its reason for you may be load all the details included avatar image(user image) so,
If you dont needed then load like this way,

```
var contacts = await PhoneBook.ContactsService.getContacts( 
    withThumbnails: false,
    photoHighResolution: false, 
  );
```

This load faster to contact book,as compare to normal way

Comment: ANd if I need avatars?